# how vifcor function works in R

Tags: r, correlation, multicollinearity

I'm using `vifcor` and `vifstep` functions from the usdm package in R to detect multicollinearity. My understanding for `vifcor` is that if I put the threshold as 0.9 for example it should give me all the variables with vif values <= 9. But the results showed much higher values (39, etc.).

So how exactly does it work and what is its relation to the vif value?

[image: vif]

Comment: If you look at the documentation for vifcor you can read about the `th` argument and what it does. I don't think there is necessarily any connection between the correlation of two variables in the dataset (max. 1) and the associated VIF (not bounded)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `vifcor`, `th` is filtering based on the correlation threshold not `VIF`. Use `vifstep` if you want to filter using `VIF`.